# Finding opcode assembly instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I have been giving a metamorphic engine a try. I started by trying to analyze the opcode assembly instruction but it does not seem to give me anything. The instruction I am looking for in the function is MOV. Why does it not return anything even though they are in the function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;


struct OPCODE
{
    unsigned short usSize;
    PBYTE pbOpCode;
    bool bRelative;
    bool bMutated;
};


namespace MOVRegisters
{
    enum MovRegisters
    {
        EAX = 0xB8,
        ECX,
        EDX,
        EBX,
        ESP,
        EBP,
        ESI,
        EDI
    };
}



bool __fastcall bIsMOV(PBYTE pInstruction)
{
    if (*pInstruction == MOVRegisters::EAX || *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::ECX || *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::EDX || *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::EBX ||
        *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::ESP || *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::EBP || *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::ESI || *pInstruction == MOVRegisters::EDI)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void pCheckByte(PVOID pFunction, PBYTE pFirstFive)
{
    if (*pFirstFive == 0x0)
        memcpy(pFirstFive, pFunction, 5);
    else
        memcpy(pFunction, pFirstFive, 5);

    PBYTE pCurrentByte = (PBYTE)pFunction;
    while (*pCurrentByte != 0xC3 && *pCurrentByte != 0xC2 && *pCurrentByte != 0xCB && *pCurrentByte != 0xCA)
    {
        OPCODE* pNewOp = new OPCODE();
        pNewOp->pbOpCode = pCurrentByte;

        if (bIsMOV(pCurrentByte))
        {
            cout << "mov instr.\n";
        }
    }
}

void function()
{
    int eaxVal;
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 5
        add eax, 6
        mov eaxVal, eax
    }
    printf("Testing %d\n", eaxVal);
}

int main()
{
    PBYTE pFirstFive = (PBYTE)malloc(5);
    RtlZeroMemory(pFirstFive, 5);


    while (true)
    {
        pCheckByte(function, pFirstFive);
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile because `bIsPUSH` isn't defined anywhere. Post your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the disassembly of `function()`?  The first instruction probably won't be `mov eax, 5`, since MSVC probably makes a stack frame in functions with inline asm.  (`push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp`).

---

Does your code actually loop over the bytes of the function?  You have a loop, but it leaks memory every iteration.  The only occurrence of `pNewOp` is, so it's write-only.

```
    OPCODE* pNewOp = new OPCODE();
    pNewOp->pbOpCode = pCurrentByte;
```

---

Note that looping over all the bytes will give false positives, because `0xb3` or whatever can occur as a non-opcode byte.  (e.g. a ModR/M or SIB byte, or immediate data.)  Similarly, you could have false positives on your `0xC3`, ... scan for [`ret` instructions](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html).  Again, look at disassembly with the raw machine code.

Writing your own code for parsing x86 machine code seems like a lot of unnecessary work; there are many tools an libraries that already do this.

Also, single-step through your C++ code in a debugger to see what it does.

Comment: would adding this: vector<OPCODE*> vOpCodes = vector<OPCODE*>(); and  this: vOpCodes.push_back(pNewOp); Prevent memoryleaks